# How can i reverse the animation?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to reverse the animation after the second click, from Top,Left to Bottom,Right.

```
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.top = pos + "px"; 
      elem.style.left = pos + "px"; 
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you add your html (and css?) so we can run your snippet

Comment: Use a different function which does the opposite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

You can change toggle on click of something too

```js
var toggle = true

function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (pos >= 350 || pos < 0) toggle = !toggle // remove this to use an event handler
    pos += (toggle ? 1 : -1)

    elem.style.top = pos + "px";
    elem.style.left = pos + "px";

  }

}
myMove()
```

```css
#animate {
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<div id="animate">*</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, can you explain how it works? plz.

Comment: I just toggle between +1 and -1 to add to the pos  - when toggle is -1, the position is reversed